# jQuery addClass removeClass with timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-loop

I have an issue with a 'Latest News' module. Please have a look at http://www.proudfootsupermarkets.com/ to see an example of the module (it's the div close to the top of the page which has a large image in it).

At the moment I have it set up so that when a user clicks on a tab the main article shows. The jQuery for this is:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $(".moduletable.latestnews article:first-child").addClass("atfront")

    $(".moduletable.latestnews article").click(function(){
        $(".moduletable.latestnews article").css("zIndex",1).addClass("atback").removeClass("atfront");
        $(this).css("zIndex",100).addClass("atfront").removeClass("atback");
    });
});
```

This is all quite simple and straight forward. The problem that I am having is that I want the articles to change automatically after a few seconds. This would then go in an infinite loop starting with article 1 and then after a couple of seconds showing article 2 etc etc...

I am sure that this is fairly simple but I have just about exhausted my knowledge of JavaScript. Thank you for any help that you are able to give :)

I have created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Bempv/

Comment: you could use setInterval and/or setTimeout based on how you want to show/hide your elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use setTimeout to change the article in front. If you select the article with the class ".atfront" and then use the `.next()` selector you should get the functionality you are looking for

```
$(function(){
    var articleToggler = function articleToggler(){
    var front = "atfront",
        back = "atback";
    return function(){
       var selection = $(".moduletable.latestnews")
                          .find("article.atfront")
                          .addClass(back)
                          .removeClass(front);
           next = selection.next("article"); 
           next = next.length ? next : $(".moduletable.latestnews")
                                   .find("article").first();
           next.addClass(front)
               .removeClass(back);
           console.log(selection.length,next[0])  


       setTimeout(articleToggler(),1000); //changes every second
    };
};

//start the rotation
(articleToggler())();
});
```

The setTimeout will call the function passed as the first argument once the timeout expires. The timeout argument is in miliseconds so the above code wait for 1 second before calling the function. Since the above function adds it self as the callback this will repeat indefinately

Comment: The line .find(":nth-child(" + i +")") creates a syntax error in DreamWeaver with the result being that it doesn't work, not sure why.

Comment: because I had inserted a ; too much on the preceeding line

Comment: Thank you for your help on this, I am using your updated code but I am getting an error on line .removeClass(back);

Comment: @user1817708 I was updating the code so didn't see your comment. Do you have the same issue with the current code?

Comment: Hi, I am now using your updated code and I am still having an error on .removeClass(back);

Comment: No errors in current code but the toggler doesn't automatically work jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Bempv/3/

Comment: @user1817708 the fiddle you linked to was not the latest code. I have no problem with the code i njsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Bempv/8/ is latest but I have changed var selection = $(".moduletable .latestnews"), to var selection = $(".moduletable.latestnews article"),

Comment: @user1817708 I've tested the current version in fiddle and as far as I can tell it works (though you do need to add at least the atfront class to one of the articles

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Got it working at http://www.proudfootsupermarkets.com with your fabulous code. Thank you again.